# History or philosophy subsites?

Tags: support, allowed-topics

Are historical questions about philosophy like -

1. What social forces were at work in forming early greek philosophy
2. Why do most people today disagree with ritual human sacrifice
3. Who invented the logical symbol for existence and why didn't they just become a physicist like their mum wanted

permitted on the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, history of philosophy is on topic per the [help center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
2. That is totally unanswerable and should be closed anywhere.
3. I don't know a logical symbol of existence. Do you mean the existential quantification ∃? In that case, that would be borderline but I think I would not vote to close it, provided that the irrelevant second half of your question would be left out.

From the link above:

> We welcome questions involving subjects like:
>
> **epistemology** — the nature of knowledge and learning
> **ethics** — the nature of the right thing to do
> **metaphysics** — the nature of being and reality
> **logic** — the nature of reasoning and inference
> **aesthetics** — the nature of feelings and artistic sentiment
> **history of philosophy** — the domains and personalities in the past associated with philosophy
> **applied philosophy** — the more specific disciplines where philosophical methods are applied, such as logic and argumentation, the philosophy of language, political and social philosophy, psychoanalysis, theology, economics, the philosophy of science and mathematics, etc.

Comment: a fair enough answer tho i don't know why 2 is unanswerable or why 3 is irrelevant

Comment: so i cannot ask about philosophical biographies ?

Comment: ps google may help you with the meaning of "logical symbol" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols

Comment: @Mathematician that page has no "logical symbol for existence". You can ask some questions about philosophical biographies, like the first half of your third example.

Comment: there is a "logical symbol for" "there exists"

Comment: but why someone studied philosophy - is part of their biography ?

Comment: @Mathematician that symbol is not commonly called "logical symbol for existence". I guessed you meant the existential quantifier, but wasn't sure, so I  mentioned my doubts. What is for you the problem with me making sure we're talking about the same thing?

Comment: i don't i enjoy speaking with you - however nervous i am of your intentions lol